# Apple Watch simulator crash randomly while debugging on Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, apple-watch

During debugging session of my Apple Watch app, simulator crash randomly with the following error: Carousel quit unexpectedly

[image: Carousel quit unexpectedly]

Comment: File a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com and be sure to attach the crash report.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, I'll do it.